# How to convert CLI Image^ into any standard C++ bitmap

Tags: c++, .net, image, c++-cli, bmp

I have loaded an JPG image to the `Image^` object but now I would like to "go back" to using standard C++ in my program so I would like to somehow convert Image^ object into any `BMP class Object`(I don't know which c++ class is good).

I would like to edit color of particular pixels in that bitmap.

Please help me do it.

```
   // a.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"
#using <mscorlib.dll> //requires CLI
using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Windows::Media::Imaging;
using namespace System::Windows::Media;
using namespace System::Windows::Controls;
using namespace a;

[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    // Enabling Windows XP visual effects before any controls are created
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

    // Create the main window and run it
    Application::Run(gcnew Form1());


    // Open a Stream and decode a JPEG image
        Stream^ imageStreamSource = gcnew FileStream("C:/heart.jpg", FileMode::Open, FileAccess::Read, FileShare::Read);

        JpegBitmapDecoder^ decoder = gcnew JpegBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource, BitmapCreateOptions::PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption::Default);
        BitmapSource^ bitmapSource = decoder->Frames[0];//< --mamy bitmape
        // Draw the Image
        System::Windows::Controls::Image^ myImage = gcnew System::Windows::Controls::Image();  //<--- this image in the Form1  -------
        myImage->Source = bitmapSource;
        myImage->Stretch = Stretch::None;


//CONVERT MYIMAGE INTO C++ BMP

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you edit pixels directly from c++/cli?  Graphics can be used to access bitmap pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the [Image.save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147.aspx) method. There you can save to a file or stream and you can specify the file format.